# Toggling content using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a accordion toggle menu that currently doesn't do much. You click on it and it opens and closes. However, i would like for it to display a "+" when closed and a "-" when open. Currently the first accordion defaults to open and displays an X and the second one defaults to + but neither change upon click aside from opening and closing.

currently the code looks like

```
                <h2 class="accordion-toggle accordion-active">HeaderText</h2>
                <div class="accordion-content default">
                    AccordionText
                </div>

                <h2 class="accordion-toggle">Headertext2</h2>
                <div class="accordion-content">
                    AccordionText2
                </div>
            </div>
      </section>
```

and the CSS looks like

```
#solution-accordion .accordion-toggle:after {
content: "+";
position: absolute;
right: 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(0);
-ms-transform: rotate(0);
transform: rotate(0);
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
}

#solution-accordion .accordion-toggle.accordion-active:after {
content: "+";
position: absolute;
right: 0;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
-webkit-transform-origin: middle center;
-ms-transform-origin: middle center;
transform-origin: middle center;
}
```

Only js for the accordion is

```
 $('#solution-accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
   //Expand or collapse this panel
   $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
   //Hide the other panels
   $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(500);
 });
```

code that is toggling the menu

```
 // solution page accordion
  $('#solution-accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
  //Expand or collapse this panel
  $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
  //Hide the other panels
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(500);
  });
```

here is a fiddle I created for it http://jsfiddle.net/WteTy/151/

I'm not the ui developer on this project, I was merely supposed to do the migration, but this was pointed out and I would like to fix it for them. Thanks

Comment: And why is this tagged as C#?

Comment: can you post the javascript code that's handling the click event?

Comment: Posted the JS that's handling the event

Comment: Your CSS and JS references markup that isn't in your post. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: Thank you Michael, I've deleted the excessive code

Comment: Just a thought.. WHy not just use jQuery UI https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#custom-icons , sometimes making the wheel better is good.. other times, just use what is already out there..

Answer (score 1):

Something in this whole process should be setting the "accordion-active" class only on the expanded accordion item.  It looks to me like it's intended to show a "+" when collapsed and then an "x" when open.  You could change the "x" in the CSS to a "-" and remove the rotations of 45 degrees.

Either way, I'd fix what they were trying to do with the addition of the accordion-active class first.

Add a removal of the class from all other elements and then add it if it's supposed to be there just for the one that is expanded.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/330nb5hk/1/

```
 $('#solution-accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
     //Expand or collapse this panel
     $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass("accordion-active");
     if($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
       $(this).addClass("accordion-active");
     }
     $(this).next().slideToggle(500);
     //Hide the other panels
     $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(500);
   });
```

Comment: thank you, I have added in the code that sets accordion-active if that helps

Comment: I do see some toggling of an 'active' class, but it's not on the 'accordion-toggle'-classed elements, nor is it toggling the 'accordion-active' class.  Maybe it's just my unfamiliarity with this particular UI component, but I still thing it's not being toggled quite properly.

Comment: You're right. i believe I found the one for accordion-toggle and edited my original comment. thanks

Comment: @DanielJ, I've updated my answer above with code that works if you replace the JS in your fiddle with it.  It looks like you'd need to pull the minus signs to the left a bit, but that's probably not an issue when it's in your complete UI.

Comment: Oh, and I'd remove the accordion-active class from the starting html and let it be added programatically, unless you are going to also set the classes to show the accordion content for that one.  Otherwise as it is it starts with the toggle icon of a minus but the accordion isn't really open.  Also, add this to start your fiddle with them closed:  

`$(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).hide();`